# IE10 body load issues when setting element font styles

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-10

IE10 seems to be ignoring how font style changes made during the body onload event effect the width of text. In this test case it ends up cropping the text short. Does anyone know why, or if this is a bug? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function SetFontFamily(FontFamily) {
    var oForm = document.forms[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < oForm.elements.length; i++) {
        elm = oForm.elements[i];
        if (elm.type != 'checkbox' && elm.type != 'hidden') {
            var bold = "";
            if (FontFamily.indexOf('-Bold') >= 0)
                bold = "bold";

            var italic = "";
            if (FontFamily.indexOf('Italic') >= 0 || FontFamily.indexOf('Oblique') >= 0)
                italic = "italic";

            var face = "";
            if (FontFamily.indexOf('Times') >= 0)
                face = "times,serif";
            else if (FontFamily.indexOf('Helvetica') >= 0)
                face = "arial,sans-serif";
            else if (FontFamily.indexOf('Courier') >= 0)
                face = "courier,cursive";

            //elm.style.font = italic & bold & face
            elm.style.fontFamily = face;
            elm.style.fontWeight = bold;
            elm.style.fontStyle = italic;

        }
        //elm.value = elm.value;
    }
    document.getElementById('hidFontFace').value = FontFamily;
}

function SetFontSize(FontSize) {
    var oForm = document.forms[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < oForm.elements.length; i++) {
        elm = oForm.elements[i];
        if (elm.type != 'checkbox' && elm.type != 'hidden') {

            if (FontSize != 0) {
                elm.style.fontSize = (FontSize * 2) + "px";
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('hidFontSize').value = FontSize;
}

function SetFontControls() {
    SetFontSize(document.getElementById('hidFontSize').value);
    SetFontFamily(document.getElementById('hidFontFace').value);
}

</script>
<title>

</title>
</head>
<body onload="SetFontControls();">
    <form method="post" id="Form1">
        <input type="hidden" name="hidFontSize" id="hidFontSize" value="9" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hidFontFace" id="hidFontFace" value="Courier-Bold" />
        <input name="txtIEtest" 
            type="text" 
            value="Why is IE10 taunting me?" 
            maxlength="120" 
            id="txtIEtest" 
            style="width:531px;height:27px;" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I get in IE10:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that IE recognizes the font-family, font-size and font-weight names as you mentioned in the javascript code?  I think the problem lies in calling `indexOf`.

Comment: It sets the font styles correctly as expected so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Atleast, `FontFamily.indexOf('-Bold')` will not be crossbrowser. You need to give number instead of string there. I mean `FontFamily.indexOf('800')` (something like this).

Comment: I don't think that's it either. FontFamily is just a poorly named variable. I am able to resolve it by uncommenting //elm.value = elm.value;... I just don't like that fix.

Comment: Not sure how that solved your problem. Anyway, I am happy to hear that you solved your problem. :)